# Zero-zero (lower indicies) term for affine connection ($\Gamma_{00}^\lambda$), why do some terms dissapear?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, tensor-calculus

More simply a tensor algebra question, but in General relativity I have the following when I calculate $\Gamma_{00}^\lambda$:-

$$
\Gamma_{00}^\lambda = \frac{1}{2}g^{\nu\lambda}\left(
\frac{\partial g_{0\nu}}{\partial x^0} +
\frac{\partial g_{0\nu}}{\partial x^0} -
\frac{\partial g_{00}}{\partial x^\nu}
\right)
=
 -\frac{1}{2}g^{\nu\lambda}
\frac{\partial g_{00}}{\partial x^\nu}
$$

Why are the $\frac{\partial g_{0\nu}}{\partial x^0}$ terms zero?

Comment: What is the metric for which you are computing the connection coefficients?

Comment: Hi rgvcorley: Echoing @joshphysics' comment: Without further context, this question seems incomplete.

Comment: @Qmechanic it's ok John M below was able to read between the lines - clearly if what I have written is true then the metric must be time invariant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of this particular metric tensor do not depend on time. $dx^j$ and $dt$ are treated as constants when you take the time derivative.

You should also have $\Gamma^{\lambda}_{00} = -\frac{1}{2} g^{\nu \lambda} \frac{\partial g_{00}}{\partial x^\nu}$.